# How to remove consecutive single letter characters from a string in python

Tags: python

I have a string as follows where I want to remove consecutive single letter characters longer than 5.

```
mystring = "the nucleotide sequence of wheat triticum aestivum l chloroplastid ribosome associated 4 5 s rna is u a g u g a g c g c g a g a c g a g c g u a u a g u g u c a g u g a g u g c a g u g a u g u a u g c a g c u g a g c a u c u a c g a c g a c g a u g a coh"
```

My output shoud be as follows.

```
myoutput = "the nucleotide sequence of wheat triticum aestivum l chloroplastid ribosome associated 4 5 s rna is coh"
```

I tried to do it as follows.

```
 for i, my in enumerate(line.split()):
     if len(my) == 1:
             count = count + 1
     else:
            count = 0
     if count == 5:
             print(i)
```

In summary, I am keeping a count and check if it has 5 length single letter characters and remove the 5 positions from the list and so on.

However, without using a variable for counting the length and removeing 5 by 5, I would like to perform this in a more efficient pythonic way.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: This is what regular expressions were made for. You want to keep `4`, `5` and `s` ? Have a look at [**`\b[augc]\s+`**](https://regex101.com/r/zOxbpK/1)

Comment: Why is '4 5 s' not in the output, if I understand the problem statement correctly?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Thanks a lot for pointing that out. It is a typo. I corrected it. Please see the edited question :)

Comment: @Jan That should answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case, we can use regular expression to solve this problem:

```
mystring = ("the nucleotide sequence of wheat triticum aestivum l"
            "chloroplastid ribosome associated 4 5 s rna is u a "
            "g u g a g c g c g a g a c g a g c g u a u a g u g u "
            "c a g u g a g u g c a g u g a u g u a u g c a g c u "
            "g a g c a u c u a c g a c g a c g a u g a coh")
print(mystring)

# See https://regex101.com/r/aUDK7K/1
# \b: word boundary
# \w: word char
# \s+: one or more white spaces
# {5,}: 5 or more times
shorten = re.sub(r'(\b\w\s+){5,}', '', mystring)
print(shorten)
```

Comment: In the general case, the last of the  single characters may not necessarily be followed by any white space as in the string 'this is an example a b c d e f g h', so I would suggest: **shorten = re.sub(r'\b(\w\s+){4,}\w\s*', '', mystring)**